# HomebrewUser error when Vagrant up

Tags: macos, vagrant, chef-infra, homebrew

I'm trying to create a Ubuntu machine with Vagrant and Chef Solo. So, I've created a simple Vagrantfile and a simple recipe, just to test it. But I'm facing with the following error message:

> Recipe Compile Error in
>   /tmp/vagrant-chef/f10d707023a689f28124f5dcfaadbc2a/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/helpers.rb
>
> ==> default: NameError
>   ==> default: uninitialized constant Chef::Mixin::HomebrewUser
>   ==> default: Cookbook Trace:
>   ==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef/f10d707023a689f28124f5dcfaadbc2a/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/helpers.rb:23:in
>   `<class:Chef12HomebrewUser>'<br/>
>   ==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef/f10d707023a689f28124f5dcfaadbc2a/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/helpers.rb:22:in<br/>`
>   '
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default: Relevant File Content:
>   ==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/f10d707023a689f28124f5dcfaadbc2a/cookbooks/homebrew/libraries/helpers.rb:
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default:  16:  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   ==> default:  17:  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>   ==> default:  18:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>   ==> default:  19:  # limitations under the License.
>   ==> default:  20:  #
>   ==> default:  21:
>   ==> default:  22:  class Chef12HomebrewUser
>   ==> default:  23>>   include Chef::Mixin::HomebrewUser
>   ==> default:  24:  end
>   ==> default:  25:
>   ==> default:  26:  module Homebrew
>   ==> default:  27:    extend self # rubocop:disable ModuleFunction
>   ==> default:  28:
>   ==> default:  29:    def exist?
>   ==> default:  30:      Chef::Log.debug('Checking to see if the homebrew binary exists')
>   ==> default:  31:      ::File.exist?('/usr/local/bin/brew')
>   ==> default:  32:    end
>   ==> default:

Below there are my files:

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "./cookbooks/teste/Berksfile"

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
   chef.install = false
   chef.add_recipe "teste"
  end
end
```

**Berksfile**

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
```

**default.rb**

```
include_recipe 'apt::default'
include_recipe 'java::default'
```

**attributes.rb**

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'openjdk'
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
default['java']['accept_license_agreement'] = true
```

**metadata.rb**

```
name 'teste'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures teste'
long_description 'Installs/Configures teste'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.1' if respond_to?(:chef_version)

depends 'apt'
depends 'java'
```

**About my configuration:**

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.3.4
chef-client version: 13.4.19
berks version: 6.3.1
kitchen version: 1.17.0
inspec version: 1.36.1

Vagrant 2.0.1

macOS Sierra (10.12.6)
```

Comment: At the top of the Chef output it should show which version of chef-solo is being used. I would guess that's something earlier than 12.7 which is the minimum requirement for the current release of the `homebrew` cookbook.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the message says _Chef 11.8.2_. But, _chef-solo -v_ I returns _Chef: 13.6.4_ as Chef version.

Comment: So you're using the default hashicorp Ubuntu image. You might have an older version of that box cached which still had chef pre-installed rather than letting Vagrant install it on the fly. If so, delete the box locally and allow it to re-download.

Comment: I tried your way, without success. I ran _vagrant box remove ubuntu/trusty64_ to remove but Vagrant still use chef-solo 11.8. How is vagrant box related to chef-solo version?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix that adding *config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest* on Vangratfile. It means Vagrant will use the latest version for chef everytime.